# System.ArgumentException: Handle must be valid. Parameter name: instance on CrossSecureStorage

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Lately the xamarin android app is crashing randomly on `CrossSecureStorage` with error as below:

```
public static string CrossSecureUserTypeKey { get; } = "UserType"; //Located in Statics.cs

var UserType = Plugin.SecureStorage.CrossSecureStorage.Current.GetValue(Statics.CrossSecureUserTypeKey);
```

> System.ArgumentException: Handle must be valid. Parameter name: type at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.GetMethodID (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, System.String name, System.String signature) [0x00009] in :0 at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.GetMethodID (System.IntPtr kls, System.String name, System.String signature) [0x00007] in :0 at Android.Content.ISharedPreferencesInvoker.Contains (System.String key) [0x00012] in :0 at Plugin.SecureStorage.SecureStorage.HasKey (System.String key) [0x0000d] in :0 at drappme.MainActivity.b__40_0 () [0x00018]

any one can help with the cause of this problem or faceing the same kind of issue.
thanks.

Comment: The issue is due to the plugin, you could add a new issue thread here https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage/issues .